# Find transformation matrix between two noisy vector sets by optimization of loss function

Tags: optimization, transformation, gradient-descent

In theory I've got two sample sets of $N$ (row) vectors $A = \{\vec{a}_0,...,\vec{a}_{N-1}\}$ and $B = \{\vec{b}_0,..., \vec{b}_{N-1}\}$ with all $\vec{a}_n, \vec{b}_n \in \mathbb{R}³$.

I can make sample sets of almost arbitrary length (arbitrary $N$). Within certain limitations that is.

There's an unknown transformation $T$ so that $\vec{b}_n = \vec{a}_n \cdot T$

Each vector $\vec{a}_n$ and $\vec{b}_n$ is also noisy so that $\vec{a'}_n = \vec{a}_n + \epsilon_a(n)$ and $\vec{b'}_n = \vec{b}_n + \epsilon_b(n)$. So the *actual* sets I'm working with are rather $A' = \{\vec{a'}_0, ..., \vec{a'}_{N-1}\}$ and $B' = \{\vec{b'}_0, ..., \vec{b'}_{N-1}\}$.

In practice I only have $A'$ and $B'$, so, only the noisy vectors.

Noise can be pretty strong, at least on $B$, noise on $A$ however not as much. And the noise is different on both vectors such that $\epsilon_a(n) \neq \epsilon_b(n)$. For simplification I assume that both $\epsilon$ are normal distributed.

I need to find the transformation matrix $T$ based on $A'$ and $B'$.

Furthermore, I think I can assume that the optimal $T$ is unique for all samples.

#### Current state

What I'm trying to do at the moment is to minimize the loss between a transformed $\vec{a'}_n$ and $\vec{b'}_n$. The loss is the reduced sum of the squared differences between all $\vec{a'}_n \cdot T$ and $\vec{b'}_n$.

I'm using Python and TensorFlow to optimize $T$, so I can't say much about the gradients. I'm also using the SGD optimizer (have tried others as well) of TensorFlow to optimize $T$.

<s>Due to the noise on $A'$ and $B'$ I can imagine that the loss and thus its gradient are not steady. That seems like a problem. Is that correct?</s> Now that I think about it, probably not.

#### So, actual questions...

1. Does this approach at all make sense?
2. Which prerequisites would this approach have?
3. Which pitfalls did I overlook?
4. Which kind of preprocessing of $A'$ and $B'$ do you think might help to stabilize the approach?
5. Can you think of other, better, more reliable approaches to get the matrix $T$ from the noisy datasets $A'$ and $B'$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach makes sense.

It sounds like you're trying to find a matrix $T$ s.t. $AT \sim B$. Here's how I would approach it.

First, consider the equation: $AT = B$
$$$$
$$\text{ $(1)$ } \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}       & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
    a_{21}       & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n} \\
    \dots \\
    a_{N1}       & a_{N2} & \dots & a_{Nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    t_{11}       & t_{12} & \dots & t_{1n} \\
    t_{21}       & t_{22} & \dots & t_{2n} \\
    \dots \\
    t_{n1}       & t_{n2} & \dots & t_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{11}       & b_{12} & \dots & b_{1n} \\
    b_{21}       & b_{22} & \dots & b_{2n} \\
    \dots \\
    b_{N1}       & b_{N2} & \dots & b_{Nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$$$

If $A$ is invertible, could just take $T = A^{-1}B$. Unfortunately, this is unlikely.

However, we can find the [minimum norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Minimum_norm_solution_to_a_linear_system) for a linear system using a [pseudo inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition):

$T \sim (A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$ which looks an awful lot like the solution for a multiple regression problem. We can also look at $(1)$ as:
$$$$
$$$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    A
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \vec t_{1}       & \vec t_{2} &  & \dots & \vec t_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    \vec b_{1}       & \vec b_{2} &  & \dots & \vec b_{n} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\iff
\begin{bmatrix}
    A\vec t_{1}       & A\vec t_{2} &  & \dots & A\vec t_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    \vec b_{1}       & \vec b_{2} &  & \dots & \vec b_{n} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$$$

This motivates the idea that you can view the decomposition problem as $n$ separate least squares multiple regression problems:

Let $\vec b_i$ be a **column vector** of $B$, then find a column vector $\vec t_i$ for $T$ such that: $A\vec t_i \sim \vec b_i$, or :

$$\vec t_i^* = argmin \text{ }||A\vec t_i - \vec b_i||^2 $$

The solution to this problem is: $$\vec t_i^* = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T\vec b_i$$ which is exactly the expression proposed above.

To make your solution more stable, you can take a [ridge regression approach](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/Rudyregularization.pdf) to each problem parametrized by some $\lambda > 0$. (Just remember to center and scale your data).

$$\vec t_i^* = (A^TA + \lambda I)^{-1}A^T\vec b_i$$

Therefore, you can break your problem up into solving $n$ separate (possibly regularized) multiple regression problems via Tensorflow. You can use SGD or Numerical linear algebra. All *should* work, and the columns of your $T$ matrix will be precisely the solutions to each regression problem.

Note that the approach breaks down when the transformation: $T: A \to B$ is nonlinear.

Comment: If I understand the term "nonlinear" correctly, T : A -> B is nonlinear if T also involves rotation, is that correct? If it is, how could this problem be solved then?

Comment: A rotation matrix is still linear, a scaling matrix is linear, a translation matrix is linear because they all act the same on every vector no matter where in the vector space. Think constant derivative. For a $2 X 2$ example, $T = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is a 90 degree rotation matrix. T is still linear, you can check that $T \cdot 0 = 0$, $Ta\vec x = aT\vec x$ and $T\vec x + T\vec y = T(\vec x + \vec y)$. Nonlinear refers to if $T: A \to B$ were something like: $B = e^A$.

Comment: Think of nonlinear as any "curvy" transformation. Something that continuously "bends" or "warps" the corners of $A$. Rotation doesn't warp anything. The idea is that if you're walking on a flat plane if you apply $T$ to that plane, will there be any hills? For rotation, scaling, there are no hills. For translation, which is quasi linear, there are no hills. Thus, in this case, the solution is still the same and it's parallelizable. Note: was sloppy above, translation is not linear because $T(0) \not =0$. you can always make affine transformations linear by centering your data.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the details, it appears the approach is working as desired... To some extent. I still have some seemingly constant bias at the end when the matrix converges that I have to examine...

Comment: No problem! Did you center your data on both sides? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia. Worst case, if that doesn't help then there may be "hills" and there is real nonlinearity, there may be a higher order term you can deal with via a kernel transform. (polynomial with degree 2).  

Good luck!

Comment: I think I did, yes. I'll have to double-check it, but I'm pretty certain I did. I'll have a look at the link that you posted later. Thanks again!